# Количество триангуляций невыпуклого многоугольника

Tags: геометрия

Добрый день. Столкнулся с такой задачей:
На плоскости заданы N точек многоугольника (возможно невыпуклого, но без самопересечений и самокасаний) своими координатами: (Xi, Yi) в порядке обхода. N <= 300. Необходимо определить количество триангуляций этого многоугольника таких, что любая диагональ содержится строго внутри многоугольника.
Я знаю, как решать такую задачу для выпуклого многоугольника: это N-2 число Каталана. Но вот что делать с невыпуклым? Возможно, нужно как-то разбить его на выпуклые и перемножить варианты в каждом. Помогите :)

Comment: [Гляньте этот вопрос](http://hashcode.ru/questions/167409/)

Comment: В данной задаче требуется посчитать количество триангуляций, а не построить одно из возможных разбиений.

Comment: @sergey_enkov: Интересный вопрос. Были какие-то продвижения за два с половиной года?